# C# Syntax error

Tags: c#, exception

Is it Syntax error or compiliing error?

```
using System;

namespace AAA
{
    class MyException : Exception{

    }
    class My2Exception : MyException{

    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            try{
                throw new MyException();
            }
            catch(Exception e){  // compiler says that this catch all exception occur          error? Is it syntax error?
            }
            catch(MyException m){  // Syntax error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it kind of syntax error?
Is this error syntax error?
thanks

Comment: I haven't actually made this kind of mistake, but similar mistakes in c# do not get caught by compiler and instead are caught by R#. For example, putting additional branching logic after a `return` or `break` statement (it gives you a warning `Unreachable code detected` but is not an error). Could that be what's happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a `catch` block for type `Exception` is the least specific exception handler possible, the need to provide a more specific `catch` block is not only redundant, but in C# it's a [**compile time error**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228623.aspx). Thus, in a multi-catch block, you should always specify the most generic `catch` block last:

```
using System;

namespace AAA
{
    class MyException : Exception
    {    

    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new MyException();
            }
            catch (MyException m)
            {  
                //TODO: something
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //TODO: something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Exception` is a more general class than `MyException` that's why you should catch it last.
As mentioned by Shaharyar it a 'semantic error'

```
try{
   throw new MyException();
}
catch(MyException m){
}
catch(Exception e){  // Syntax error
}
```

Comment: I know that :D
but is it "Syntax error" ?
Or what kind of error?

Comment: @Gui_C well, it's not a syntax error, as everything is written using valid C# syntax. Just a compile-time error